# OrderBy on non unique columns will work in index scan?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

```
id    market_id      date          keyword                 sku            a             b         c  
1        1        2019-01-01    some text for this      QAB-XU-VV        3.1           2.4       3.5
2        2        2019-01-02    some text for text      ABC-XA-VV        2.1           4.1       1.2
3        1        2019-01-03    some text for XXX       DDD-XA-RR        2.7           3.5       4.1
```

I need to query like this

```
   SELECT
      sku,
      keyword,
      SUM(a),
      SUM(b),
      SUM(c),
    FROM A
    WHERE market_id = 2 AND date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and '2020-02-02'
    GROUP BY sku, keyword
    LIMIT 10
    OFFSET XX
```

I used `SampleTable`(assume this table as `SampleTable`) and `SampleTable(sku, keyword)` composite-index. so this query will do `index scan`. query time is fast but I need to add `LIMIT...OFFSET` for pagination.So what I need to know is that this query will sort as `SORT BY ID`? I can't use `ORDER BY ID` since if I use this, this query will do `file sort` and will be very slow since it will use `full scan` instead of `index scan`. Here is what I'm confusing.

> MySQL has two ways to produce ordered results: it can use a filesort,
>   or it can scan an index in order.
>
> Ordering the results by the index works only when the index’s order is
>   exactly the same as the ORDER BY clause and all columns are sorted in
>   the same direction (ascending or descending).
>
> The ORDER BY clause also has the same limitation as lookup queries: it
>   needs to form a leftmost prefix of the index. In all other cases,
>   MySQL uses a filesort.

Please help me what I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: If no explicit ORDER BY clause then no additional ordering. In ancient MySQL version GROUP BY (which needs in sorting for to be performed) also causes this sorting to applied ot the output rowset (if no ORDER BY clause specified), in recent version it is not applied (but it may, and, in many cases, occures, if no ORDER BY).

Comment: *So what I need to know is that this query will sort as SORT BY ID? I can't use ORDER BY ID since if I use this, this query will do file sort and will be very slow since it will use full scan instead of index scan.* You MUST use any ORDER BY, because LIMIT without ordering is a lottery (i.e. if you then will execute the same query with another LIMIT borders nothing prevents from to obtain the same records, fully or partially). If you want to avoid filesort then use the same ordering expression which is used in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. Yes. so if I use `Order By sku,keyword` then it will prevent obtaining same records and should be good to use for `LIMIT... OFFSET` without any concern?

Comment: `LIMIT .. OFFSET` always have the same problem which is not relative to ordering - it enumerates records until OFFSET then fetched the amount of records specified in LIMIT. The larger OFFSET the higher the time elapsed. This enumeration is inner, hidden, and unrelative to any enumeration which already exists (i.e. none enumeration which already exists will be reused).

Comment: Yes. you're right. I'm experiencing this issue too now. I just want to know whether there is no duplicated records if I use `ORDER BY sku, keyword` instead of using clustered index(PRIMARY KEY) `ID` column.

Comment: After `GROUP BY sku, keyword` the duplicates by `sku, keyword` presence is impossible even in theory.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` each want to scan the entire table.

*One* index *may* help.

In your query, `INDEX(market_id, date)` (or an index starting with those two columns) can avoid a full table scan and scan only part of the index.  But that does nothing toward the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.  Furthermore, since the `WHERE` clause is not all `=` tests, tacking on the `GROUP BY` columns is futile.

If you were able to get past the `WHERE`, then `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` lead to separate passes *unless* they are 'identical'.

I believe your query, as it stands, is doomed to need 4 passes:

- Scan over index to handle the filtering by `WHERE`.
- Sort and "group" the resulting temp table
- Sort for `ORDER BY`.
- Skip over `OFFSET` rows; only then can you deliver the 10 desired by `LIMIT`.